# Using "ping" on a relative basis

Tags: networking, ping, website

I am very new to any technical stuff and just trying my hands on the good old ping. I was wondering what information can be extracted, if any, from studying the difference between ping results of two sites. 
It wrote a short script to ping my blog and google.com and plot the difference between respond time, packet loss.. for 24 hours. I am not positive what conclusions can be drawn safely, and can it be used to eliminate some possible network issues and narrow down to the issues with the server.

Answer (score 2):

Ping is designed to show the time it takes for a packet to traverse a network to any given computer system and send back a reply. In it's most basic form, it simply indicates time in millisseconds to receive a response from any host that you are attempting to communicate with. There is a very large amount of information on the web documenting the use of ping. I would open up a search on google and do some reading on the basic use of ping. To answer more specifically for what you're trying to accomplish; the difference between pinging one website or server and then pinging another is only a relative indication of how fast your connection (or slow in this case) is to google or your blog. To better understand what you're trying to determine, you need a baseline of what should be a normal acceptable amount of time to reach your blog or google from whatever location you're pinging from. Only then, will you be able to determine if the connection has degraded to a slower response over time or if it's a temporary hiccup in the network response. There are numerous factors that can cause a slow response. Ping is a great tool but you may need to also utilize other network utilities to better isolate a slow or degraded connection. In this case, www.google.com will help gleam alot of information as this topic is fairly mature.